# Need advice on how to architect my app back end using Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, architecture

Should I use Firebase as just a back end utilizing all the cool features like Authentication, DB etc it provides or should I use something like Google App Engine to interface with Firebase?

I am planning to build a mobile app (MVP). This app will let users anonymously sign in and do what the app lets the user do. Now there will be lot of CRUD operations on the database. I have done my analysis to see what kind of database to use, what kind of authentication to use. I have tried using the REST APIs exposed to some extent. Everything drives me to use the Firebase directly but I want to know from experts here what is the best practise. Just to let you all know, this is a MVP but planning to put in production so I can have Beta users try out and provide constant feedback.

Comment: This isn't a bad question but it's really asking for an opinion which is off-topic for SO. The main problem is that we would need to understand your entire use case to make an accurate suggestion - and that obviously goes way beyond what can be done here. When you say 'use Firebase directly' what does that entail? For example, if you wan to work with coordinates, you could roll your own 'directly' but why spend months coding that when you can lean on GeoFire to handle Geo location tasks. I would head over to the Firebase google group which is a lot more free form for discussion.

Comment: Thank you! I have posted my question in google group!

Comment: @Jay   I guess, i wasn't clear. My question was should my mobile make calls to Firebase directly using sdk or should i route via cloud functions. I found a good link which was  suggested in the group. I think I am clear now. But again still long way to go before I make a good decision. [link] (https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c)

Comment: It would be impossible to make a recommendation without understanding the scope of the project. However, Firebase was designed to be a cloud based, event driven database so why *wouldn't* you use the sdk? Cloud functions are a different beast entirely and are designed to respond to HTTP requests which at a app device level you wouldn't be doing (generally speaking). Again though it depends on the use case.